# How can I modify an instance of the button defined in a Cell Header?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following XAML class:

```
 <ListView Controls:ListViewColumns.Stretch="true"
                  Name="myListItems" SelectionMode="Single">
<ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header> 
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="btnDelete" 
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        Padding="0"
                                        Margin="0"
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolConverter}, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WO:OpCompTab}}, Path=DisableAll}"
                                        Click="btnDelete_Click" Tag="{Binding Path=.}">
                                    <Image Source="/Win7;component/Images/Icons/Remove.png"
                                        Width="{StaticResource IconWidth}" 
                                        Height="{StaticResource IconHeight}" />
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
               </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The listview gets populated by hooking an observable collection up to its ItemSource property. This generates a neat looking column of **Delete** buttons for each item in the observable collection.

But this presents a quandary: How do I access the "btnDelete" of an individual row of the ListView? I'd like to change its icon on a per-row basis. Is it just a matter of binding the observable collection to the cell template somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the Image.Source, bind it to a property in your row object. Another way is to create a value converter and pass in the row or some property if you can't or don't want to modify the row object to add an ImageSource property. Have the value converter return the correct image source based on the passed in property or some other logic.